# Get no of the day in that year using given date

Tags: bash, date

For example I gave 31-dec-2020 it should return 365th
I tried in bash with below but its not working.

```
start_of_year= "2020-01-01"
echo "enter date in yyy-mm-dd format"
read current_date
difference=  `expr $current_date - $start_of_year`
echo "day of the year $difference"
```

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112453/how-to-get-day-of-the-year-in-shell

Comment: That question was about getting current day of the month using date command, but what i need is random date will be give from user input

Comment: @nullPointer no my question was specific to day of the year. and your post was about difference bw two dates

Comment: Your usage of `expr` does not make sense. The arguments are strings, not numbers. You can't make a difference between strings. See _man expr_.

Answer (score 0):

```
date -d "$current_date" +%j
```

The `%j` formatter returns the day number in the year. See *man date*.

Comment: Haven't a clue why you were downvoted. This is the correct answer.```$ date -d "Mar 1 2021" +%j
060
$ date -d "Mar 1 2020" +%j
061```